# Given that there is only one correct answer for this question, which one is the correct answer?

Tags: logical-deduction

A. Neither B nor C is the correct answer.
B. Neither C nor D is the correct answer.
C. Trust me, this is the correct answer.
D. Neither A nor B is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct is

> **B**

because

> if B is correct,
>  C is necessarily false;
>  A is false because B is correct;
>  D is false because B is correct.

You can see that

> A cannot be correct, as then C and D are false, making B correct also.
>  C cannot be correct, as then A and B are false, making D correct also.
>  D cannot be correct, as then B and C are false, making A correct also.